# ABAP: Event CONTEXT_MENU_SELECT of CL_SIMPLE_TREE_MODEL - can't fire it

Tags: event-handling, contextmenu, abap

I have an instance of `CL_SIMPLE_TREE_MODEL`, I managed to trigger and handle the `CONTEXT_MENU_REQUEST` event, and I build my context menu.

I added my functions the way I wanted.

Problem is, when I select one of the options from my context menu, nothing happens. In other words, the program flow doesn't go inside the handler for `CONTEXT_MENU_SELECT`.

I'm of course assuming this event is fired when I click on a function in the context menu.

I found official documentation, but only for the "default context menu" that you access with Shift+F10, that needs certain subroutines in the program in order to fire.

What I did:

1. I did define and implement a method that is a handler for that event.
2. I did set the handler for the event at the same place I set the handler for the `CONTEXT_MENU_REQUEST` event
3. I did NOT register the event with the `SET_REGISTERED_EVENTS` because there is NO ID defined in the class attributes for that event - such as there was for the `CONTEXT_MENU_REQUEST` event.

The code:

```
REPORT.

CLASS lcl_tree_handler DEFINITION.

  PUBLIC SECTION.
    METHODS:
      pbo,
      on_ctx_menu_request FOR EVENT node_context_menu_request OF cl_simple_tree_model
        IMPORTING node_key menu sender, "TYPE TM_NODEKEY CL_CTMENU
      on_ctx_menu_select FOR EVENT node_context_menu_select OF cl_simple_tree_model
        IMPORTING node_key fcode. "TYPE TM_NODEKEY SY-UCOMM
    DATA:
      po_tree_model TYPE REF TO cl_simple_tree_model,
      gt_tree       TYPE TABLE OF treemsnodt,
      control       TYPE REF TO cl_gui_control.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS lcl_tree_handler IMPLEMENTATION.

  METHOD pbo.
    DATA: lt_events TYPE cntl_simple_events,
          ls_event  TYPE cntl_simple_event.
    FIELD-SYMBOLS <gs_tree> TYPE treemsnodt.

    CHECK po_tree_model IS NOT BOUND.

    CREATE OBJECT po_tree_model
      EXPORTING
        node_selection_mode = po_tree_model->node_sel_mode_single.

    APPEND INITIAL LINE TO gt_tree ASSIGNING <gs_tree>.
    <gs_tree>-node_key = 'Node key 1'.
    <gs_tree>-text = 'First node'.
    <gs_tree>-isfolder = 'X'.
    APPEND INITIAL LINE TO gt_tree ASSIGNING <gs_tree>.
    <gs_tree>-node_key = 'Node key 2'.
    <gs_tree>-relatkey = 'Node key 1'.
    <gs_tree>-relatship = cl_tree_model=>relat_last_child.
    <gs_tree>-text = 'First child'.
    po_tree_model->add_nodes(
          node_table = gt_tree ).

    ls_event-eventid = cl_simple_tree_model=>eventid_node_context_menu_req.
    ls_event-appl_event = 'X'.              "tried with space too
    APPEND ls_event TO lt_events.

    CALL METHOD po_tree_model->set_registered_events
      EXPORTING
        events = lt_events.

    SET HANDLER on_ctx_menu_request FOR po_tree_model.
    SET HANDLER on_ctx_menu_select FOR po_tree_model.

    po_tree_model->create_tree_control(
      EXPORTING
        parent = cl_gui_container=>screen0
      IMPORTING
        control = control ).

  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD on_ctx_menu_request.                 "I initialize the context menu object here.
    DATA: lt_chidren_keys TYPE treemnotab,
          ls_child_key    TYPE tm_nodekey,
          lv_text         TYPE gui_text.

    CALL METHOD sender->node_get_children
      EXPORTING
        node_key       = node_key
      IMPORTING
        node_key_table = lt_chidren_keys
      EXCEPTIONS
        OTHERS         = 2.

    LOOP AT lt_chidren_keys INTO ls_child_key.
      lv_text = ls_child_key.
      CALL METHOD menu->add_function
        EXPORTING
          fcode = 'ONE'
          text  = lv_text
          ftype = 'B'.
    ENDLOOP.

    menu->add_separator( ).
    CALL METHOD menu->add_function
      EXPORTING
        fcode = 'ALL'
        text  = 'All the work groups'
        ftype = 'W'.

  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD on_ctx_menu_select.
    BREAK-POINT.                 "tried actual code here too.
  ENDMETHOD.

ENDCLASS.


DATA: go_tree_handler TYPE REF TO lcl_tree_handler.

PARAMETERS dummy.

INITIALIZATION.
  CREATE OBJECT go_tree_handler.

AT SELECTION-SCREEN OUTPUT.
  go_tree_handler->pbo( ).

AT SELECTION-SCREEN ON EXIT-COMMAND.
  go_tree_handler->control->free( ).
```

The tree is displayed, on right click the context menu appears.

But nothing fires when I chose a menu item. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Could you please provide a short demo program? It's hard to figure out what might be missing from your description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function types you specify (`ftype = 'W'` and `'B'`) are not supported (check the fixed values of the underlying domain `CUA_FUNTYP`). In that case, nothing happens.

The classic solution is to use `ftype = ' '` (normal function):

```
    LOOP AT lt_chidren_keys INTO ls_child_key.
      lv_text = ls_child_key.
      CALL METHOD menu->add_function
        EXPORTING
          fcode = 'ONE'
          text  = lv_text
          ftype = ' '.
    ENDLOOP.

    menu->add_separator( ).
    CALL METHOD menu->add_function
      EXPORTING
        fcode = 'ALL'
        text  = 'All the work groups'
        ftype = ' '.
```

The possible `ftype` values are (source: domain `CUA_FUNTYP`):

- ' ' : Normal function
- 'H' : Help function (PROCESS ON HELP REQUEST)
- 'S' : System function (handled directly by DYNP)
- 'T' : Transaction call (LEAVE TO TRANSACTION)
- 'E' : Access modules for 'AT EXIT COMMAND' -> /E as prefix
- 'I' : Include menu (replaced at runtime - not supported)
- 'N' : 'AT EXIT COMMAND' Function, > DYNP > /N as Prefix

Remark: the code in the first version of the question was missing the registering of the second event handler `SET HANDLER go_tree_handler->on_ctx_menu_select FOR po_tree_model.` (now it's okay)

Comment: How about the function types?

Comment: thank you for being freaking awesome! -first time seeing this kind of behavior.